# How to return multiple values from a function in C

Tags: c, pointers

How come the pointer in `main` does not get updated to the string that starts with 'xavier' instead of returning to its initial value!

Here is my function:

```
char * getValue(char * tag, char * query)
{
    char * end = strstr(query, "&");
    while (* query != '=')
    {
        query++;
    }

    query++;
    // print the query string after the pointer has been incremented through while loop

    printf("%s \n", query);

    // get the size of the substring I want
    int size = strlen(query) - strlen(end);
    printf("%d \n", size);

    // allocate memory for it and link it to pointer 'value'
    char * value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    memcpy(value, query, size);
    value[size] = '\0';

    printf("%s \n", value);
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
    char * tag = "Username=";
    char * query = "Username=Xavier&Password=Bachelor&Submit=+Create";

    char * value = getValue(tag, query);
    // Username=Xavier&Password=Bachelor&Submit=+Create This is the result after the f() of the printf
    // Xavier&Password=Bachelor&Submit=+Create This is what I want...
    printf("%s \n", query);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. What "pointer in main" and "string that starts with xavier"?

Comment: I understand that through pointers we modify multiple values within a function and be able to access them through main, I thought query would get updated, but sadly it does not! How do I correct that! Thanks

Comment: Please include the code which calls this function (i.e. relevant code from `main`)

Comment: Sorry forgot to post the results of the program

Comment: Can you explain which statement in the `getValue` function you expect to have the effect of updating the pointers in `main`? Also, what do you expect `return value` to do, when the call `getValue(tag, query)` ignores the return value?

Comment: I know how to get the return value of a function() I am just apparently terrible at expressing a question! Sorry about the confusion. char * value = getValue(tag, query) should be in the code I will fix that, I would like to have pointer that points to "Xavier&..." in main... is there a way, without using a struct

Comment: PS I wrote the code, I'll make a better job asking my question next time! Thanks

Comment: @user3366297 asking effective questions at SO is its own skill, and almost everybody needs to learn it the hard way, so no problem. Looking at answers, none got it so far. I'll write answer once I get to non-virtual keyboard, but to modify original value you need to pass pointer to it, so in this case, pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify parameters, you need to pass pointer to the value you want to modify.

1. Since you want to modify pointer, you need to **pass pointer to pointer**.
2. This is more a matter of opinion, but many programmers think that using out parameters is a bit ugly. It can lead to code which is harder to understand. To mitigate this, parameter name should reflect what it is, for example in the way shown below.
3. In general, always make any pointer parameters be pointers to *const*, unless you actually do need to modify what it points to. With strings it's especially important, because string literals are read-only, and usually pointers to string literals are made const. If you function takes pointer to non-const, then you should get compiler warning or error (depending on what exactly you do).
4. Since `tag` is unused at least in the question code, you should get compiler warning about that (and if you don't, you should turn up warnings!).

Fixing all this gives this function:

```
char * getValue(const char * tag, const char **query_in_out)
{
    (void)tag; // remove compiler warning about unused parameter

    char * end = strstr(*query_in_out, "&");
    while (**query_in_out != '=')
    {
        (*query_in_out)++;
    }

    (*query_in_out)++;
    // print the (*query_in_out) string after the pointer has been incremented through while loop

    printf("%s \n", *query_in_out);

    // get the size of the substring I want
    int size = strlen(*query_in_out) - strlen(end);
    printf("%d \n", size);

    // allocate memory for it and link it to pointer 'value'
    char * value = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    memcpy(value, *query_in_out, size);
    value[size] = '\0';

    printf("%s \n", value);
    return value;
}
```

Call by passing address of pointer you want to modify:

```
char * value = getValue(tag, &query);
```

---

PS. As I said above, C string literals are normally read-only, so you should really have this:

```
const char * tag = "Username=";
const char * query = "Username=Xavier&Password=Bachelor&Submit=+Create";
```

That way, you can modify these pointers to make them point to different things (like your `getValue` function doesw), but you can't accidentally modify the data they point to (which would crash the program in case of string literal, on a modern OS).

Comment: Btw, hint for tool which can help getting C declarations right, web version: http://cdecl.org/?q=declare+query_in_out+as+pointer+to+pointer+to+const+char%3B or on your local linux, `cdecl`/`cundecl` commands may be installed.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Have you try to use another object.
The Object with many properties. So when you return an object you can get or set many values

Comment: I know i can make a struct, but its possible to do it just with pointers, that's what I would like to do

Comment: The question is marked as `C`, not `C++`. And using objects is more related to a `C++`

Comment: I constructed a struct, it makes a lot more sense! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not capturing the return value from the function. You can do...

```
printf("%s \n", getValue(tag, query));
```

Comment: I have the right return value the problem is that I would like to get "Xavier=...." as a new query so that I can change the tag and make a call again getValue() until there is no more value to parse...

Comment: Your code is `getValue(tag, query); printf("%s \n", query);` - you don't use the value you built in `getValue`, you print the full query

Answer (score 1):

The C language has "pass by value" semantics for function parameters.

When the `main` function executes

```
getValue(tag, query)
```

the *argument expressions* `tag` and `query` are reduced to their values. These values are now dissociated from the variables from which they came: copies of these values travel into the function, where they are used to initialize the parameters `tag` and `query`:

```
char * getValue(char * tag, char * query) { ... }
```

these parameters have nothing to do with `tag` and `query` in the `main` function, even though they have the same names. These parameters are *local variables* of the `getValue` function, exactly  like the `value` variable and the `end` variable. Like `value` and `end`, they are newly created when the function begins executing. Unlike `value` and `end` they are special: being parameters, they are initialized with the argument values received from `main`.  When `getValue` returns, all of these local variables are destroyed (though not what they point to!).

When you increment the `query` pointer, you are only changing the local variable, which is gone when that function is done.

Your program also leaks memory: the `getValue` function allocates space and uses the `value` local variable to track this space and store some characters into it. It then returns that pointer via the `return value` statement. At that point, the `getValue` function stops executing and the `value` variable ceases to exist, but the memory from `malloc` continues to exist: the pointer value is returned out of the function. Then the previously suspended `main` function resumes executing but, alas, it ignores the value returned from the `getValue` call. That memory has become unreachable: the program has lost its last remaining copy of the pointer that it obtained from `malloc`, and has no way to refer to that memory at all, let alone free it with the `free` function. That situation is called a "memory leak".

Comment: I know that I need to assign cha * value = getValue() to get my return value from the f(), I forgot to free() the memory thanks! But how do I update the "query" string without using a struct? Is that possible, thanks

Comment: Actually, where should I free() the block of memory allocated for thre char * value of the getValue() function, if I free it before the return statement I will lose the 'value'

Comment: @user3366279 I'd say, don't worry about it until you get the program working right. Your OS will clean up the memory when the program exits, so the leak is not a big problem in actual fact. Memory leaks are a big problem when they repeatedly occur in programs that run for a long time.  It's better to suffer a small leak than to free memory and then continue to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In `C++` you could use address of variable instead of variable in function defininion, like this

```
char * getValue(char * tag, char * &query)
```

In plain `C` you only can use pointer to pointer to achieve same functionality:

```
char * getValue(char * tag, char ** query)
```

Of course, in function budy you should then use dereference, i.g. using `*query` instead of `query`, and you should call this function like `getValue(tag, &query)`

Comment: @hyde, then it can be done by char **, and call the function like `getValue(tag, &query)`... It's still more answer to this than using a struct...

Comment: @hyde, I'm edited my answer according to your comment. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, much better, +1. I wanted to express a few more points, so I wrote an answer too, though your answer makes partly redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple values you have to define a structure and return an object of that type.

I think you make a confusion in your program. You probably want to do this in main.

```
query = getValue(tag, query);
```

If you don't capture the return value how do you expect anything to be updated?

Comment: There is a way to do it with pointers, I would like to avoid using a struct.. Sorry for the confusion, I will make a better job explaining my problem next time, the return value is fine I just want to get the modified "Xavier=..." so that I can look for the substring "Bachelor" Thanks